# GraalVM debugging in VS Code not available

Tags: debugging, native, vscode-extensions, graalvm

Debugging native java application is supposed to work with Visual Studio Code after installing GraalVM Tools for Java. However, the described launch type "nativeImage" is not available after installing extension. Any hints how to get this running?

Documentation: (which doesn't work as described)
https://www.graalvm.org/22.1/tools/vscode/graalvm-extension/debugging-native-image/

Regards
Harry

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently](https://docs.oracle.com/en/graalvm/enterprise/21/docs/tools/vscode/graalvm-extension/debugging-native-image/#debug-native-images-in-vs-code),

> To debug a native image from within VS Code, you must install GraalVM
> Enterprise.

Comment: Thanks. I already did that. Looks like the plugin has changed and does no longer support debugging.